# Where to put a constant array?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a function which has several constant arrays with many numeric values. These arrays contain the coefficients for polynomial equations and don't change. For now I defined the arrays in the same function (.cpp File), for example:

```
    double coefficients[7] = {
        271.155123745294,
        -2.03521046106355,
        8.79645207223641E-03,
        -1.38958348112727E-05,
        -2.048607610462E-08,
        9.372391616E-11,
        -8.397701E-14
    };
```

Looking at my code I'm not very happy with the "look" of the code and asked myself if there is a nicer solution (e.g. putting a bunch of constant values in a separate file or in the header). It is not really a problem but in my opinion the reader gets distracted from the algorithm.

Comment: #define co1, co2, co3 .. [Preprocessor Directives](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/)

Comment: @FirstStep Why on earth would you use a preprocessor macro when you can use a proper const variable instead?

Comment: Which language?   You describe a .c file (suggesting C language) but have tagged the question as C++.   There are some options that would be preferable in one language or the other.

Comment: Its .cpp, just changed it. Thx.

Answer (score 4):

You can put your constants in their own file and `#include` them where you need them - that's not a problem.

Btw, you *say* constants, but in your example your array is not `const` - but it could be if you don't intend to change it.

Answer (score 3):

You can

- put the array constants in a namespace along with the function (an anonymous namespace is probably good enough),
- put them in the global namespace as `static` constants, along with the function (note: this use of `static`, for data, is deprecated)
- put them in separate accessor functions, which can be `static`.

By the way, do add `const`.

That informs also the compiler that they're constant.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing, apart from the above answers: put it in a config file. You can only do this if you don't need it in compile time, but then you can update the constants without recompiling/redisting the code. It can still be a const, given you can read and parse the config file during static initialization.

Comment: “One man's constant is another man's variable.” – old jungle proverb

Answer (score 0):

You should have used `const` type qualifier for your double variable `coefficients`.

> Looking at my code I'm not very happy with the "look" of the code

Yes, you were right. It doesn't look good and there are better ways to do it.

You could achieve better readability if you have used `static` modifier with your variable and place it outside the function definition. Or you can just make it global in `.cpp` file just above the function definition that is going to access it.

And yes, `separate accessor functions` (make it `static`) is also a good idea as mentioned in one of the answer.

You can also try [X Macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) if it helps in code readability issues.